# Passing parameters on button click in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, parameter-passing, ruby-on-rails-5

Right now, I have it so that when users pick an option from `collection_select`, a div is populated based on the `event_id` of their choice. Depending on the `Event`, there will be multiple `EventOption` shown, each with their own unique ids. (I have `EventOption` as `belongs_to` `Event`, each of which `has_many` of them.)

This is what I have populating via JS/Ajax when they select an `Event`:

```
<div class="center" >
  <h2>Available Options for "<%= @event.name %>":</h2>
    <% @event.event_options.each do |e| %>
      <p><strong>Name:</strong> <%= e.name %> </p>
      <p><strong>Description:</strong> <%= e.description %></p>
      <p><strong>Price:</strong> <%= e.price %></p>
</div>

<div class = "center row">  
  <div class = "col-xs-6">
      <%= link_to "Check Available Dates", root_path, :class => "button", :id => "available-dates-button" %>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-xs-6">
     <%= link_to "Book This Event Now!", book_now_path(:event => @event.id), :id => "book-now-button", :class => "button" %>

  </div>    
      <hr>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

My issue is that I can pass the `event_id` when they click the `Book This Event Now!`, but that's not what I need. I need the specific `:id` of the `:event_option` to be passed over, and I don't know how to get it from the iterated `.each` I have it coming from.

How can I make sure that each iteration of a button that follows my `book_now_path` has a unique ID that I can use to complete their reservation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `event_option.id` to your `book_now_path` helper.

```
book_now_path(:event => @event.id, :event_option_id => e.id)
```

Then in the controller action it will be in the params:

```
@event_option_id = params[:event_option_id]
```

You can add any additional parameters to the Rails routes helpers simply by adding their names and values as keys and values to the helper method's options.

Comment: That makes entirely too much sense! Thank you! And I will be able to pass @event_option_id into my forms and such to call the other columns I need, I presume?

Comment: @GeekFitness, I presume you mean forms in the views from the `book_now` action, so yes.

Comment: When testing `@event_option_id` in `book_now.html.erb`, I keep getting no value coming back up. It is showing in my server logs as `Parameters: {"event"=>"4", "event_option_id"=>"5"}` but when I try to use `<%= @event_option_id %>` it comes back blank, and when I just tested it as .to_i, it showed `0` instead of `5`. Any idea?

Comment: @GeekFitness, Be you sure you are assigning the param to `@event_option_id` and not `event_option_id`.  Otherwise, this is really a new question.  If you want to open another question and post your code, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yep, it's using `@event_option_id`. That was my first thought. I posted a new question and elaborated a bit. Thank you so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048592/passed-parameters-not-being-read-in-rails