# Passed parameters not being read in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I posted this question earlier: [Passing parameters on button click in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046857/passing-parameters-on-button-click-in-rails/39047083)

And the answer works very well. However, I the passed parameters aren't able to be called in erb, even the `@event_option_id` that is being passed from the `book_now` method.

It is showing in my server logs as `Parameters: {"event"=>"4", "event_option_id"=>"5"}` but when I try to use `<%= @event_option_id %>` it comes back blank, and when I just tested it as `to_i`, it showed `0` instead of `5`.

My `EventsController` has this method:

```
def book_now
  @event_option_id = params[:event_option_id]
end
```

And my link is passing the parameters like this:

```
<%= link_to "Book This Event Now!", book_now_path(:event => @event.id, :event_option_id => e.id), :id => "book-now-button", :class => "button" %>
```

I am trying to pass this `@event_option_id` so that I can access the corresponding values from my db.

Each `EventOption` has a `price`, `description`, and `name` that is unique to it, and when I try to access those in multiple ways, I get `(NoMethodError: undefined method 'price' for nil:NilClass)`, for instance.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: where in your controller, are you saving the values to your DB? And have you confirmed that they are actually being saved? Passing params successfully does not mean they are actually making it into the DB.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, actually. The entries and params already already exist in my DB. The user selects from a dropdown, the app takes that event_id and populates a div with the associated model's options. When the above button is pressed to send these parameters to the booking page, I just need to call the associations that are already there. Does that make sense?

Comment: well if the event object already has a event_option_id that exists, then have you tried calling it with `@event.event_option_id` from your view?

Comment: I get `undefined method `event_option_id' for nil:NilClass` for that, too. I am just baffled on this one.

Comment: have you tried the solution below? He is saying that you need to actually find that event option object, and bring in the WHOLE object, so that you have access to all it's info. what you are doing now is getting it's ID but not any of it's other info. To do that, you need to put `@event_option_id = EventOption.find(params[:event_option_id])` in yourEventsController where you currently have `@event_option_id = params[:event_option_id]`

Comment: I would change that variable name to `@event_option`. From there you should be able to access it in your view using `@event_option.price, @event_option.name, @event_option.description` if that solution works for you do make sure you mark his answer ;)

Comment: I did do that, and that's why I'm still baffled. It isn't doing anything but pulling `nil`, even with  I get why it **should** be working, but there's obviously something going on I don't know how to trace down. It's either `undefined method 'price' for nil:NilClass` or coming up blank.

Comment: you should install the gem better error, it will help you debug. just in general. on another note it sounds like your event itself is coming up nil. are you able to display other information about the even that is not part of the event options?

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely do that. Because there is most certainly a disconnect. I can get the models to connect with these lines of code in `rails c` and using `e = EventOption.find(5)` brings up the 5th `EventOption`, and  `e.price` does return `35.0` in `pry`. But when I do it via Rails itself, I get `nil`.  #confuzzled

Comment: @GeekFitness, how about posting your actual controller and view code for the book_now action, since that's the code in question?

Answer (score 1):

With `@event_option_id = params[:event_option_id]` you are just assigning the event_option_id param value to an instance variable.

What you should be doing is finding the corresponding `EventOption` object with the event_option_id as follows:

```
@event_option = EventOption.find(params[:event_option_id])
```

With that piece of code in the controller method, `<%= @event_option.price %>` in the view will show the price of that `EventOption` object.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but which controller should this be in? I have done it in both `EventsController` and `EventOptionsController`, and I get `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass):` from both.